# What type of small diameter motor/generator is best for for a hand-crank cell phone charger

Tags: motor, battery-charging, charger, brushless-dc-motor

Currently, I'm designing a hand-crank cell phone charger and I found it difficult to chose the right motor that would fit my design.

The thing is that I need a very thin motor (0.6in (16 mm) diameter) but the ones that I have only deliver around 0.02 A and 5 V. I also I have a bigger motor that works perfectly and gives me 0.1 A and 4 V. But it is 1 in (25 mm) diameter so it is way too big.

The motor that I'm looking for can be very long, up to 4in (100 mm), but can't be thicker than 0.6in.

Any advice where if something like that exists? or maybe I need to use some other type of motor?

I am also using a boost converter.

Thanks!

Comment: Shopping is off-topic.

Comment: @brhans this is a bit out of style for me, but to me this looks like OP is asking for the *type* of motor to look for, so it's a proper problem and approach description more than a shopping question...

Comment: @Anton: You may need to modify your question to make sure that you are not in violation of the [Don't ask](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) rules.

Comment: Smaller motors will only produce less power. (depending on weight of magnets)  But V/RPM needs to be chosen correctly. Such that it is maybe 25% higher with no load at desired RPM.

Comment: It is unlikely that such a motor exists. A long thin motor is more difficult to manufacture. You could look for a DC motor with a commutator and brushes, but brushless permanent-magnet motor would provide more power for a given weight and volume. I don't see this as anything but a shopping problem.

Answer (score 5):

A cellphone battery contains about 10-12 Wh (sometimes more).

If this is an emergency charger, and we're in a  hurry, we will only charge it partially, doing only the CC phase where the battery accepts the maximum amount of power, and skipping the CV charge at the end.

In the CC phase most phones would charge at 1C and thus input 5V at a maximum of 2A. Most likely it will be less, around 1-1.5A if the onboard buck charger is of good quality, the power supply can supply the current and the phone identifies it as able to do so...

Thus someone will need to crank the crank on your charger for at least one hour while generating a tiny amount of power like 5-10W.

Who would want to do that when you can use a solar panel instead and not waste an hour of your time and get sore fingers? Unless the idea is only to provide a small amount of charge to make an emergency call.

In this case I would suggest to get rid of the crank, and replace it with a pull cord.

Or you could try something like the GravityLight...

Anyway, back to your generator.

The idea for a generator is to have high \$ d\phi / dt \$ ie fast variation of magnetic flux in your coil, because this is what determines output voltage and thus power. For the same size of coil and magnetics, the more \$ d\phi / dt \$, the better.

Thus your alternator will look like a pancake. Think about a [claw pole alternator](https://www.google.fr/search?q=claw%20pole%20alternator&safe=off&client=opera&hs=ZsE&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwir8-Lw3rbXAhWPhRoKHde8Ca4Q_AUICygC&biw=1277&bih=745#imgrc=rXvvh1nFF_UNzM:) for example. A magnetic circuit creates a number of poles on the circumference. Individual magnets can also be used, not getting into details here, but the idea is that at the same rpm, a wider diameter makes the poles run faster in front of the stator coils, which generates more \$ d\phi / dt \$.

This is why [this alternator](http://www.globalsources.com/si/AS/Shenzhen-China/6008828762958/pdtl/10W-Micro-Alternator/1114179028.htm) looks like a pancake.

If you want a thin cylinder, you're out of luck. Won't work unless you use insane RPM. And you're unlikely to find one on the market, because everyone else will opt for the optimum shape... either pancake or a rather stout, not thin, cylinder.

Comment: "everyone else will opt for the optimum shape" absolutely gets my vote :)

Comment: Amazing answer! thank you for taking your time to elaborate! You're right, it will be an emergency charger. What about Volts? is it better to have a 6,12,or 24V motor?

Comment: Volts = a bit above fully charged battery at your favorite RPM, don't use a boost converter, just use more turns in your coil, it's cheaper ;)

Comment: Also I like the string instead of a crank: it uses muscle strength a lot more efficiently and won't give you blisters ;) check this inflator for an example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eqBH9XZ7lwQ#t=0m55s

Comment: Awesome thing, just add a usb there and you have a winner) But I really need it to be a crank. The truth is that today the product has to look cool to find a customer which is why my design needs a really skinny motor.

Comment: Go for pancake motor and put the crank handle on the flat side not on the skinny edge. See [crank+torch](https://www.google.ie/search?rlz=1C1PRFC_enIE653IE653&biw=1050&bih=1614&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=vfAGWqvTOYbNgAaTq43ICg&q=crank+torch&oq=crank+torch).

Comment: Well, your customer trouble won't change physics. Also, why would emergency equipment need to be stylish instead of useful? A slim body is harder to hold and hence less desirable. Also, compare with how much charge you'd get out of a lithium battery that would have a longer shelf life than any modern phone charging methods would be around. I don't feel like you're building a product that meets an actual demand.